# Show string result from function in a label using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

What is the best way to call function that will return string and show that string in a label when using angularJs?

I have three drop downs, and when I select values in all of them I want to show a label. 
Content of a label is calculated in one function so on that moment (when all 3 drop downs have some values selected) I need to call function that will return value for label as well.

All that hiding/showing label logic I have put in html like this:

```
<div class="col-md-2" 
        ng-show="newTestSessionCtrl.formData.sessionTime && newTestSessionCtrl.formData.timeZone && newTestSessionCtrl.formData.sessionCloseInterval">
    <lable>Your local time</lable>
    <div ng-value="convertSelectedTimeZoneToClients()"></div>
</div>
```

This is convertSelectedTimeZoneToClients() function code:

```
convertSelectedTimeZoneToClients() {
    let timeZoneInfo = {
        usersTimeZone: this.$rootScope.mtz.tz.guess(),
        utcOffset: this.formData.timeZone.offset,
        selectedDateTime: this.toJSONLocal(this.formData.sessionDate) + " " + this.formData.sessionTime 
    };

    let utcTime  = this.$rootScope.mtz.utc(timeZoneInfo.selectedDateTime).utcOffset(timeZoneInfo.utcOffset).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
    let localTime = this.$rootScope.mtz.utc(utcTime).toDate();
    localTime = this.$rootScope.mtz(localTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
    return localTime;
}
```

So when values are selected I am showing label that says: Your local time
And underneath I want to show result from `convertSelectedTimeZoneToClients()`that will be basically string in '**YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm**' format.

Can I preform something like this on the html as well or I will have to move to controller? What is the best or easiest way to accomplish this?

I have tried ng-value, but I guess I am doing wrongly. Nothing gets show, but I do not get any errors in console as well.

Comment: can you show your code for this function convertSelectedTimeZoneToClients()?

Comment: use `<div>{{convertSelectedTimeZoneToClients()}}</div>`. Also **ng-bind** is better than braces.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Hello, I have tried both, but for some reason my function is never called...

Comment: @nemo_87 please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

in your function you can check if your drop downs are selected, then calculate and return result

```
$scope.getData = function () {
        if ($scope.ValueOfFirstDropDown != undefined && $scope.ValueOfSecondDropDown != undefined && $scope.ValueOfThirdDropDown != undefined) {
            //calculate result
            return result;

        }

    }
```

and in your html

```
<label>{{getData()}}</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div ng-bind="convertSelectedTimeZoneToClients()"></div>
```

Comment: It most certainly does work :) Perhaps your `convert...` function is not returning anything, or the clause in `ng-show` returns false?

Comment: Well the label is shown when I select some values from drop downs, so ng-show is not a problem. And when I look in the console I see that function returns string value... But it never gets shown... Maybe the order of generating things is problem? @wroniasty

Comment: it returns plain text. I've updated question and added implementation of function. But now I realized that it never gets invoked or called... So that is where the problem is... Breakpoints are never hit...hmm @wroniasty

Comment: You should call this function on change of selected value. and set another scope variable and reflect it their.

Answer (score 0):

You should call this function on change of selected value

```
<select ng-change="convertSelectedTimeZoneToClients();"></select>


<div class="col-md-2" 
        ng-show="newTestSessionCtrl.formData.sessionTime && newTestSessionCtrl.formData.timeZone && newTestSessionCtrl.formData.sessionCloseInterval">
    <lable>Your local time</lable>
    <div ng-bind="clientDateTimeZone"></div>
</div>
```

and reflect `$scope.clientDateTimeZone = yourreturnedvalue`

No need to return any thing

```
   $scope.convertSelectedTimeZoneToClients = function()  {
    let timeZoneInfo = {
      usersTimeZone: this.$rootScope.mtz.tz.guess(),
      utcOffset: this.formData.timeZone.offset,
      selectedDateTime: this.toJSONLocal(this.formData.sessionDate) + " " + this.formData.sessionTime
    };

    let utcTime = this.$rootScope.mtz.utc(timeZoneInfo.selectedDateTime).utcOffset(timeZoneInfo.utcOffset).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
    let localTime = this.$rootScope.mtz.utc(utcTime).toDate();
    localTime = this.$rootScope.mtz(localTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
    //set It here
    $scope.clientDateTimeZone = localTime
      //return localTime;
  }
```

Comment: I have change everything as you've said, and it really looks like a good solution, but still for some reason my function is not called even on ng-change. I have put ng-change in every single drop down, but nothing. When I select some values label: 'Your time zone' is shown but there's no result, since function is not called for some reason... :/ @ParthTrivedi

Comment: Your function should be like `$scope.convertSelectedTimeZoneToClients = function() {  //code } `

Comment: That can be the problem. My function is not in $scope. I have constructor in Controller for setting everything up, injection, etc, and out of the constructor I have functions. Maybe I should call function from constructor? @ParthTrivedi

Comment: @nemo_87 got success?

Comment: No :( Still trying. I cannot change the form of controller, or define $scope outside of constructor where is injected, but when I do this:
this.$scope.convertSelectedTimeZoneToClients();
My whole html gets broken for some reason... :/ @ParthTrivedi

Comment: You can try global variable and set `$scope.clientDateTimeZone `  it from global variable on chnage event.

Comment: where it is setted `newTestSessionCtrl.formData.sessionTime`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127704/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-nemo-87).